# What are some options for logging .NET exceptions and messages in a cloud environment?

Tags: .net, exception, logging, azure, cloud

I currently have a web application running on Microsoft's Azure platform with multiple web and worker roles. What I would like to be able to do is log all exceptions and messages to a SAAS product so that all developers in my team can easily search through and respond to issues.

Have any of you used or know of a good logging tool that can be used with a cloud based web application?

Comment: Have a look at [loggly](http://www.loggly.com/features/). 200mb logs / day and 7 days rentention is for free. They have a very nice functional ui and a great search engine.

Comment: I might be a bit late, but you should consider using [elmah.io](https://elmah.io). Unlike ELMAH (the open source project), elmah.io offers both error management of exceptions as well as message logging. You can either log manually or use integrations for Serilog, log4net etc. elmah.io is like your product hosted in Microsoft Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Standard `Trace.WriteLine` and `Trace.Error` functionality is a very straightforward solution. Azure Diagnostics supports writing this output to a Table Storage.

You can then view the log data with something like [Azure Diagnostics Manager](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/AzureDiagnosticsManager/)

Comment: I'm curious what the downvote was for. I've been using this exact solution for years and it works fine.

Comment: Does this work for Azure WebApps as well? I know it does for Worker Roles and VMs.

Answer (score 0):

- Log4Net/NLog + Loggly/(ElasticSearch + Kibana) + Pager Duty can be a good set
- Raygun can be another option